# on tomcat latest images and CSS files are not showing latest updates after deployment

Tags: tomcat, web, browser-cache

I am deploying my web-app on **tomcat** and using services of AWS. Some time before I have enabled web cashing by adding filters in web.xml .

```
<filter>
 <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
 <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter</filter-class>
 <init-param>
    <param-name>ExpiresByType image</param-name>
    <param-value>access plus 1 week</param-value>
 </init-param>
 <init-param>
    <param-name>ExpiresByType text/css</param-name>
    <param-value>access plus 1 week</param-value>
 </init-param>


</filter>

<filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

When I am updating CSS files and images with same name then changes didn't reflecting until unless, I made  them check-in as a  **new file /images**. **Even after I remove all filter** problem remain still. Can someone help into this issue ?